# Exception while connecting to MySql from java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to MySql db in WAMP server using Java code. The server is in a machine inside the local network. Following is the code I use:

```
public class MySQLAccess {

public static void main(String args[]) {

      String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.21:3306/";
      String dbName = "mydb";
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String userName = "root"; 
      String password = "";
      try {
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
      System.out.println("Connected to the database");
      conn.close();
      System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
      } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

And I get the following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection timed out

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at MySQLAccess.main(MySQLAccess.java:24)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



    Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at MySQLAccess.main(MySQLAccess.java:24)
```

There is nothing obvious I can see in this code that should cause this exception. Also, I have reconfirmed the port number is correct and the hosting machine do not have any firewall.

What can be the cause of this issue and what could be the solution. Any melp is much appreciated.

Comment: are you able to ping your db server machine from your machine?

Comment: Is you mysql server configured to accept remote connections ?

Comment: It seems a simple connection error. try to connect from the same machine that you use to run the code to the mysql server using an other mysql client. You have to exclude any connection problem first.

Comment: @MayankSharma - I am able to ping

Comment: Are you granted to access the DB server? @user1400538

Answer (score 1):

1.Check whether your mysql is running on purticular host and port

2.Try pinging that host from the machine your code is running to ensure the connectivity (firewall ??)

3.If you have a db ui [tool](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_gui_tools.htm) or something, try to connect using that